# How can I interact with objects inserted with ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Let's say I have a file called `example.html` that looks like this:

```
<button>Click me</button>
```

Now let's say I have another file called `index.html` that contains this:

```
$.get('example.html',function(data){
  $('body').html(data);
});
```

How can I do this...:

```
$('button').click(function(){
  $(this).hide();
});
```

...from my `example.html` file?

Comment: How can you do "what"? There is **NO** difference between DOM elements created initially and in runtime.

Comment: If I do `$.get... $('button').click...` it doesn't work because `$(button)` didn't exist when the page loaded. How can I work around this?

Comment: "didn't exist when the page loaded" --- so attach the event handler **AFTER** it's added to the page. Isn't it obvious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.get('example.html',function(data){
  // load
  $('body').html(data);

  // use
  $('button').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: This is the one I went with, so simple and requires no extra code. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You need to delegate the event to the static parent:

change this:

```
$('button').click(function(){
```

to this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
```

because your content is getting loaded via ajax call so initially it was not available in the dom where it is getting loaded so in that case your direct event binding won't work.

To get this work one has to delegate the event to the static parent and in your case you can delegate to `body` or `document` itself to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the click handler registered to the button element is not getting triggered....

The solution is [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
  $(this).hide();
});
```

When you use a normal event registration model, it will register the handlers directly to the targeted which are present in the dom at the point of the handler registration execution. So elements which are added later dynamically will not get those handlers.

The solution to this is to use event delegation, in this model the handler is registered to a ancestor element which will be present when the page is loaded with the a selector to filter out the source element. This makes use of event propagation - events happening in an element is propagated to all the ancestor elements(there are few exceptions like focus event). So an event happening in an element gets propagated to the ancestor element in one of them the handler is registered then the events source element(event.target) and its ancestors is matched against the selector passed as the second parameter, if it is satisfied then the handler is executed.